# Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null. Don't know the reason

Tags: flutter, compiler-errors

I know this error has been answered already man times but i think my condition is bit different. My flutter was running nice till now without any dificulty. But suddenly it started giving me this error during run of app.It is not opening on app on installing.This error just keeps coming during installation of app and i don't know from where its coming.[image]

Please guide me how to find the location of problem and how to resolve it.

Comment: Post the code..

Comment: Can you edit your post with the code part that gave the error ?

Comment: very hard to help without the code - but I think you can't find the snippet that's causing the error and its not feasible to post your entire app lol.

Comment: my guess is that something broke in that 'green earth' package (if this is an import) - maybe remove it from pub spec and comment out references to it in your code and try running the app

Comment: please look into this post.I found the error but solving it is too much https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66124273/update-value-of-variable-of-inherited-widget @TirthPatel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is probably accuring because you are giving a null value to `jsonDecode`:

```dart
var jsonString = null;
var parsed = jsonDecode(jsonString);
print(parsed.length);
// NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null.
```

Search your project for `jsonDecode` or `json.decode` and ether don't call it when `jsonString` is null and show an error message, or replace it with a default jsonString:

```dart
var jsonString = null;
const defaultJson = '{}';
var parsed = jsonDecode(jsonString ?? defaultJson);
print(parsed.length);
// 0
```

Comment: thanku very much, can u look into this post too!!! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66124273/update-value-of-variable-of-inherited-widget